# Audio Source and Blender Capabilities

Tags: video

Forgive me, but I am 100% new to Blender.  I have just begun experimenting.  I am hoping to build a music video in the application.  My hope is to have individual tracks from the song (example snare drum, basslines) some in and be a modulation source of some kind in the program to trigger video, move animation, etc.  Is this possible and where can I do some preliminary reading on an approach like this?

Thanks much,
Tim

Comment: I think you are looking for the `Bake Sound to F-Curve` feature